# Determine whether a folder is present?

Tags: java, file, filesystems, io, java-io

How would I go about determining whether a file or directory has been created in Java?

I basically want to create a data directory if one is not already present.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`File#exists()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) to determine if it exists, but you can also just call [`File#mkdirs()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) to automatically create the whole path if not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this technique:

```
    File folderLocation = new File("/blah/blah/mysystem/myfolder");

    if (folderLocation.exists()) {
        if (!folderLocation .isDirectory()) {
            throw new IOException("File-system item with path [" + folderLocation.getAbsolutePath() + "] exists but is not a folder.");
        }                
    } else {
        if (!folderLocation.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Could not create folder with path : " + folderLocation.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    // we are guaranteed that the folder exists here
```